# How to get data recycleview to parse on other updateactivity?

Tags: android-recyclerview

I have code in `ListBukpotAdapter`, how can I get data `listener.OnClick(currentItem)` to parse on other `UpdateActivity`

Error:

**kotlin.UnitializedPropertyAccessExeption: lateinit property listener has not been initialized**

```
class ListBukpotAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListBukpotAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private var bukpotList = emptyList<QrResultBukpot>()

    private lateinit var listener: OnAdapterListener

    interface OnAdapterListener {
        fun OnClick(bukpotDataParsing: QrResultBukpot)
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {}

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.custom_row_bukpot, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return bukpotList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = bukpotList[position]
        holder.itemView.txtNomorBukpot.text = currentItem.nomorBukpot
        holder.itemView.txtNpwpPemotong.text = currentItem.npwpPemotong
        holder.itemView.txtMasaPajak.text = currentItem.masaPajak + " / " + currentItem.tahunPajak
        holder.itemView.txtMixCode.text = currentItem.mixCode

        holder.itemView.rowLayoutBukpot.setOnClickListener {
            listener.OnClick(currentItem)

            val context =  holder.itemView.context
            val intent = Intent(context, UpdateBukpotActivity::class.java)
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    fun setDataBukpot(bukpot: List<QrResultBukpot>){
        this.bukpotList = bukpot
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initilaze your listener. Your listener variable is lateinit so before you use this, you need to initialize. You can give listener as a constructor parameter from your activity or fragment and can listen interface from your activity or fragment which contains recyclerview.